# Displaying text if post was within 5 hours

Tags: php, functions

Currently I have the following string.

```
$timeago = human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') );
print $timeago;
```

This returns results that looks like this.

1 min, 1 hour, 1 week, 1 month, and 1 year.

I am trying to figure out how I can make this work using an `if` statement to detect if the post has been posted within the past 5 hours, and if it has make it echo "**NEW**" but if not, don't echo anything.

**EDIT:** 
I tried the following with no success... I am getting confused on how to make it check for the hours portion as well as the number portion I guess.

```
$timeago = human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') );
print $timeago;
if( $timeago >= 0 && $timeago <= 5 )
{
    print 'NEW';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`human_time_difference()` will not work here as it returns a string in a human readable form. However, we can use some of the logic used there to construct a workable function

You can try the following: (***Untested***)

```
function get_custom__time_diff()
{
    global $post;

    // Get the current time
    $current_time = time();
    // Get the post date
    $post_date    = get_the_time( 'U', $post );
    // Get the amount of seconds in 5 hours
    $test_time    = 5*HOUR_IN_SECONDS;
    $diff         = $current_time - $post_date;

    if ( $diff < $test_time )
        return 'New';

    return '';
}
```

You can then call it as follow inside the loop

```
echo get_custom__time_diff();
```